# Error when installing Hadoop 2.3.0 on Windows 7

Tags: exception, hadoop, windows-7-x64, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am following the installation process outlined in the link: 
http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os

When running the 'start-dfs' command I get the following error:

FATAL namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

Any suggestions on how to fix this and finish configuring Hadoop? Thanks!

Comment: 1. Look in <Hadoop-home>/bin and see if there is a hadoop.dll. If no, there was an error building. 2. If the first if ok, make sure you have you `%HADOOP_HOME%` env var. 3. make sure you have <hadoop-home>/bin in your %PATH%.  --- the exception is caused by hadoop not being able to link correctly to the native code in (generally in the hadoop.dll)

Comment: Yeah, the hadoop.dll doesn't exist. But I don't recall any errors before the one above. What can I do about it? Which step should I repeat?

Comment: Did you follow the step _exactly_ from the tutorial? The first time I installed Hadoop on Windows, I used the tutorial you used, and it worked. I had to reinstall again for an unrelated reason, but the second time I went of [this tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows). They're pretty similar, except in the second one, cygwin isn't required. It uses CMake to compile to native code. You can see the [Building.txt](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/branches/branch-2/BUILDING.txt?view=markup) file that comes with the installation. Try the second tutorial.

Comment: See if you can get it to work. Also it was required that I used a Windows SDK command prompt, not the standards Windows one

Comment: Don't use windows ;) Seriously, why try to do Big Data on an OS designed for writting letters on word, or accountants to calculate taxes!

Comment: What to use then? Would you recommend some virtual machine for example?