# start-dfs.sh namenode start name or service not knownstname 0.0.0.0

Tags: windows, hadoop, cygwin

I want to install `Hadoop` on windows with

```
Cygwin
```

, i can see the interface from localhost:8088, but the problem is with `start-dfs.sh`, i see the error : name or service not known .. , and i can't acces to `localhost:50070` or `:50030`.

[image: start-dfs.sh message error]

the first error is fine , i've already worked with it in linux , so my problem is with the second error .

> ADD
>   when i type `hadoop namenode` ,
>   everything is fine except in the end :

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us which service is unknown, as nothing is there related to it in screenshot.

Comment: this is the problem , i don't know either .

Comment: These are just warnings and not errors.

Comment: i can't access localhost:50050 because the namenode is not well started .

Comment: i have add a second screenshot .

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440223/error-when-installing-hadoop-2-3-0-on-windows-7

Comment: i tried , i have the hadoop.dll , still the same error .

Comment: Did you format `namenode`?

Comment: yes , i did , actually , i switch for linux , worked better .