# When Hadoop 2.7 start on windows 7 64 bits: Name or service not knownstname localhost

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

I am installing Hadoop on window 7 64bits with Cygwin. 
After I format the Hadoop successfully, I want start it use the command:
 start-dfs.sh.
but it reports as:

```
$ sbin/start-dfs.sh
17/03/26 17:35:27 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
]tarting namenodes on [localhost
: Name or service not knownstname localhost
alwang@localhost's password:
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/alwang/hadoop/logs/hadoop-alwang-datanode-alwang-lt.out
]tarting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0
: Name or service not knownstname 0.0.0.0
17/03/26 17:37:48 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

[Name or service not knownstname localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMnBE.png)

Here is my config files:
**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>  
    <property>  
　　　　<name>fs.default.name</name>  
　　　　<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>  
　　</property> 
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>  
<property>  
　　<name>dfs.replication</name>  
　　<value>1</value>  
</property>  
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:/hadoop/data/dfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:/hadoop/data/dfs/datanode</value>
</property>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
   <configuration>  
    <property>  
　　　　   <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>  
　　　　   <value>localhost:9001</value>  
　　    </property>  
　　    <property>  
　　　　   <name>mapred.child.tmp</name>  
　　　　   <value>/home/u/hadoop/tmp</value>  
　　    </property>  
</configuration>
```

I have noticed there is someone else asks this at the link:
[name or service not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644264/start-dfs-sh-namenode-start-name-or-service-not-knownstname-0-0-0-0)

But till now there is no correct answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update your post with NameNode logs

Answer (score 0):

I've been troubleshooting this issue on my Ubuntu servers. Regarding the "WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your..." Check your environment variables and make sure that your Java path is pointing to the 64 bit binaries. That fixed the issue for me.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I will try to do that. But for the "Name or service not knownstname localhost " issue, I have some idea, I think the Cygwin should be configed to know thhe localhost, but I don't know how now. I will read some document and search on the site to learn.